# where clause with includes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` model which has has_many relationship with `Identity` model.
I want to execute `includes` query with where clause.

```
User.includes(:identities).where("identities.provider = 'facebook')
```

But it is giving me error.

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table
>   "identities"

while it works fine with joins

```
User.joins(:identities).where("identities.provider = 'facebook')
```

I don't want to use scope. I just want to use `where` like I do with joins clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [**APIdoc**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

> If you want to add conditions to your included models you’ll have to
>   explicitly reference them

When using `includes` with ***conditions***, you need add `.references` at the end. The below should work

```
User.includes(:identities).where('identities.provider = ?', 'facebook').references(:identities)
```

Comment: Is there any special reason for adding `references` ? why can't we do it like normal join